# 8GB USB disk listed at only 512B or 10MB?

Tags: arch-linux, dd, parted

I made an Arch Linux ISO USB drive, and I'm trying to restore it using
the [directions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#How_to_restore_the_USB_drive) from the Arch Linux wiki. After running:

```
$ sudo dd count=1 bs=512 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde && sync
```

`parted` only recognizes one sector with 512 bytes:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sde -s print
Error: /dev/sde: unrecognised disk label
Model:  (file)
Disk /dev/sde: 512B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

And I'm unable to create new partitions:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sde -s mklabel msdos
$ sudo parted /dev/sde -s mkpart primary fat32 0% 100%
Error: Can't have the end before the start! (start sector=1 length=0)
Error: Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
```

Leaving out the `count` and `bs` flags for `dd` result in only 10MB
being written, and not the whole disk:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde && sync
dd: writing to ‘/dev/sde’: No space left on device
20481+0 records in
20480+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.0177212 s, 592 MB/s
$ sudo parted /dev/sde -s print
Error: /dev/sde: unrecognised disk label
Model:  (file)
Disk /dev/sde: 10.5MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Comment: Try erasing the current partition table before writing a new one. `fdisk`/`gdisk`/`parted` should be able to do that.

Comment: you are replacing the sd**x** with sd**e** in your first command, correct?

Comment: @sam Yes, I'll edit my answer to reflect that. @John I thought that's what the initial `dd` command was doing... ? I don't see any options to erase partition tables in `fdisk` or `parted`; only to delete partitions.

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the right disk? What's the output of `grep sde /proc/partitions`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As hinted by Gilles), you are not working on your USB device.

Clue number one is the `Model` on the output of

> ```
> $ sudo parted /dev/sde -s print
> Error: /dev/sde: unrecognised disk label
> Model:  (file)                                     <= file!
> ...
> ```

- Your command:

  ```
  sudo dd count=1 bs=512 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde && sync
  ```

creates a zero filled file at `/dev/sde` of 512 bytes.

- When you try to write to entire disk by:

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde && sync
  ```

you write to the file `/dev/sde` until there are no more space left on partition holding `/dev`.

```
    dd: writing to ‘/dev/sde’: No space left on device
```

As `/dev`, (most likely), is actually RAM disk, ([udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev)), you exhaust the limit set on that partition ...

When working with `dd` as you do, working on the correct disk is ***extremely*** important. If you had another disk named `/dev/sde` it would have been erased. Completely. As noted in your linked Arch Wiki:

> **Warning:** This will irrevocably destroy all data on /dev/sd**x**.

---

**After plugging in the USB device, look at for example:**

```
lsblk
```

if you want more information do for example, see *man* or `-h`:

```
lsblk -o NAME,STATE,RM,HOTPLUG,TYPE,TRAN,SIZE,PHY-SEC,LOG-SEC,FSTYPE,MODEL,VENDOR,LABEL,PARTLABEL
```

---

**And:** Devices does ***NOT*** get the same **`dev/xxx`** entry each time. It is random.

#### Other notes:

When you do:

```
sudo parted /dev/sde -s mklabel msdos
```

you create a `msdos` partition table in the ***file*** `/dev/sde`. This works fine. But when you then proceed by:

```
sudo parted /dev/sde -s mkpart primary fat32 0% 100%
```

you try to create a primary partition in the file and get the error:

```
Error: Can't have the end before the start! (start sector=1 length=0)
```

because it refuses to start the partition at sector 0, where your partition table, here *msdos*, resides. Thus it test for *start* sector 1, or offset 512. But as the file is only 512 bytes the *end* sector would also be at 512 and you get a *“end before the start”*.

The minimum size for a fat32 partition is anyhow 65,527 clusters, or about 32MB.

Comment: Indeed, and in the process I wiped my password vault (sorry for the late reply lol). Make sure to check your UUIDs kids! Thanks for your help

Comment: @randomdev2: Ups. That's too bad. Guess at least it is lesson learned. God luck on your Linux journey ahead.

Comment: This is very informative explanation, many thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 3):

I solved a very similar problem with:

```
rm /dev/sdb
```

with my usb drive plugged-in (and listed as /dev/sdb).

After that, I can create a new partition table for the whole drive.

Comment: You saved my day. It seems somewhere along the line I accidently created `/dev/sdg` and so when my drive appeared as `/dev/sdg` it only shown `/dev/sdg1`. I did not have a clue why `fdisk` shows weird information, but removing `/dev/sdg` solved my problem.